Accessing Route Params React Native Issue
I am trying to pass an array of data from one page to another in React Native. When I console.log route, I can see the params, but when I log route.params, it is undefined.
Code for passing data from Input to Home
Code for logging and receiving data in Home
Console output
I tried accessing route.params and route.params.data but both of them are undefined even though I can see them when I log the route variable.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

route is passed into HomeScreen component as a prop. You should access route via HomeScreen's first argument (e.g. prop.route) or destructure route (e.g. function HomeScreen({ route }). Voting to close this as "caused by a typo".

In future please add code to the question so its easier to update and provide an answer.
You need to change this line to the following:

const {data} = route.params || {data: []};

// to this

const {data} = route?.route?.params ?? {data: []};

